# Tools for building and exporting high resolution geotiff

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I'm having some really nice raster maps in geotiff format. I would like to add some features to these maps as well as then exporting them as tiles for serving the map from a web server.

Preferably I would want to be able to work with the different geotiff files in a software like QGis or similar. As I want to add some vector components and combine the different TIFF files before I export them to one big geotiff with all features needed.

Though my biggest problem is that in QGis I can't export geotiffs with higher resolutions than the current screen resolution, which makes it rather pointless as I'm working on a quite big map.

So I'm wondering what possible ways there are to do what I have just described. Can I combine QGis with any other tools or how would you do it?

Comment: You can always go directly to gdal and use translate, warp og calc  to do your data manipulation.  Furthermore you can prepare your tiff for Web serving with pyramids etc.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181451/67583 for how to export pretty geotiffs from the QGIS composer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a "Save as" option for raster layers which can be used to export raster layers at high resolution.

Considering combining raster layers, have a look at the Raster Calculator functionality.