# How to get a PNG image of a polygon with the corner coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, coordinates, png, qgis-2.8

How to get a PNG image of a polygon with the corner coordinates in a separate file?

I have access to ArcGIS 10.1 and QGIS 2.8.1.

I tried this:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30503/50606
, but I get an uncomplete file :

**0.01192239336492888**

**0**

**0**

**-0.01192239336492888**

**15.35022462480259975**

**-10.64971119668243738**

The 2 last lines are the coordinates of the North-West corner (WGS84). I don't know what the first 4 lines represent. And I don't know how to get the 3 other coordinates.

---

Using the "Generate World file" in Atlas does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**0.01192239336492888 is your pixel size**
see more information on world files

so you can work this out if you know the number of pixels your image is

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file you only need your top left for images in ArcGIS

TO SAVE TIME:

you know you can use
**Build Footprints** (Data Management)  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000087000000

"Computes the footprints for each raster dataset in a mosaic dataset."